# How to "Show in Finder"?

Tags: macos, file, swiftui, finder

In SwiftUI for macOS, given a `URL` for a local file, I would like to be able to activate the Finder and open a window showing the file's enclosing folder, with the file selected.

In AppKit, this is the function of `NSWorkspace`'s `activateFileViewerSelecting(_:)` method.

Does anyone know how to achieve the equivalent in native SwiftUI?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be a "native SwiftUI" call for this -- it's exclusive to macOS and doesn't have anything declarative about it. Probably just keep using `activateFileViewerSelecting`?

Comment: I hear you, @jnpdx. I've recently gotten into macOS and was surprised to see the reach of the SwiftUI methods, even in file management and the like. I've still not once had to import AppKit… Maybe I've just gotten spoiled by that!

Comment: Actually you still don't have to import AppKit. When you import SwiftUI, it pulls in AppKit for you. 

Answer (score 1):

As @jnpdx pointed out, this is really an example where "the same old way" from AppKit works just fine:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([url])
```